# How can I check which column is wrong in the insert statement?

Tags: java, sql

I created a database and want to fill it with data using Java, but this table gives me some difficulties.

```sql
CREATE TABLE doctor (
    id INTEGER,
    employeeID CHAR(10) CONSTRAINT doctor_uk UNIQUE,
    specialisation VARCHAR(255),
    drugcertificate INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT docotr_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT doctor_fk FOREIGN KEY (employeeID) REFERENCES employee
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT doctor_drugcert_check CHECK (drugcertificate Between 0 AND 1 )
);
```

I created the table with no problems whatsoever, and I am able to fill it with data using oracle sql developer.
But when I try to run this Java code I get the error msg:

> ORA-00984: Column Not Allowed Here

And in the Java file, before that loop is another loop which fills another table and that works just fine. So it is just this for loop that doesn't work.

```java
for(int amount = 0; amount < 10; ++amount) {
          int drugcertificate = (random.nextDouble() >= 0.5? 1 : 0);
          String insertDocotr = "INSERT INTO doctor(doctorId, employeeId, specialisation, drugcertificate) VALUES ("+(amount+1)+", "+
                                        employeeIDs.get(amount)+", "+doctorSpecial[amount%4]+", "+drugcertificate+")";

          int rowsAffected = stmt.executeUpdate(insertDoctor);
      }
```

employeeIDs is a List with a few type Long numbers and
doctorSpecial is an Array of Strings.

What should I change? I don't get it.

Comment: strings in mysql need to be delimited with single quotes, e.g. `'a string'`.  Note that concatenating sql queries like that is very insecure and opens you up to sql injection attacks.  Try using prepared statements https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: allright is noted :) thanks!

Comment: Also is there a reason not to use auto-genrated ids？